# Agregar imágenes en un slider de Drupal

Tags: drupal

He intentado agregar imágenes al slider de [mi web](http://marinagolfrapel.cl/).

Sé que el carrusel se modifica desde el bloque llamado slider que tiene este código:

```php
<?php
$titulo      = "";
$imagenes    = array();
$img_count   = 0;
$description = "";
$style_blur  = "blurred_and_smallest";

if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ! arg(2) ) {
    $node = node_load(arg(1));
    if ($node->type == 'page') {
        $titulo      = $node->title;
        $description = count($node->field_page_descripcion)>0 ? $node->field_page_descripcion["und"][0]["value"] : "";
        $imagenes    = $node->field_page_slider["und"];
        $img_count   = count($imagenes);
    } else {
        $node_noticias = node_load(7); // 7 : nodo de noticias
        $imagenes      = $node_noticias->field_page_slider["und"];
        $img_count     = count($imagenes);
    }
}
?>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <?php foreach ($imagenes as $key => $value) :
            $img_link  = $value["alt"];
            $img_title = $value["title"];
            $img_xl    = file_create_url($value["uri"]);
            $img_thumb = file_create_url(image_style_path($style_blur, $value["uri"]));
        ?>
            <div class="item <?= $key==0?'active':'' ?>">
                <div class="carouselDivImg b-lazy" data-src="<?=$img_xl?>" style="background-image: url(<?=$img_thumb?>);">
                        <?php
                        if(strlen($img_title)>0 || strlen($img_link)>0) {
                            echo "<h3>";
                                if(strlen($img_title)>0){ echo "<p>$img_title</p>"; }
                                if(strlen($img_link)>0){ echo "<a href='$img_link'>Haz clic aquí</a>"; }
                            echo "</h3>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>

    <?php if($img_count > 1): ?>
        <div class="sliderFlechas">
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-menu-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

</div>
```

Lo que no comprendo es cómo el antiguo desarrollador creó el vector llamado imágenes ¿dónde y cómo escogió las fotos? He buscado con un editor de texto masivo en todos los códigos de esa web y no encuentro nada relacionado.

Comment: ¿Y se ha hecho a mano tocando los `tpl` directamente o desde _views_ o algun otro módulo?

Comment: No creo que sea una vista, he ingresado al menú de vistas y sólo hay 3 habilitadas que se llaman Webform Analysis, Webform Results, Webform Submissions y Webforms. He ingresado a cada una y no entiendo casi nada y no hay nada similar a un apartado para elegir imágenes. Quizás sea un template, pero no tengo ni idea, ni de como buscarlo.

Comment: He trabajado con Drupal pero no controlo mucho la parte de la programación. Yo diría que coge las imágenes de un campo personalizado llamado `field_page_slider` de diferentes tipos de contenido. No estoy muy seguro de esto pero quizá te sirva para encontrar las imágenes

Comment: Gracias. Estaba leyendo sobre los "nodos" y creo que las imágenes del slider van en ese nodo llamado field_page_slider. Voy a seguir investigando si alguien me dice como ubicar el nodo, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Busqué con el editor de texto masivo en todos los archivos de la web y no arrojó resultados para ese texto.

Comment: ¿Y si entras en el tipo de contenido _página_ (o page) desde la administración de Drupal no hay un campo con ese nombre?

Comment: He revisado en el menu contenido (nodo) y vistas, pero aún no encuentro las imágenes.

Comment: Drupal al igual que wordpress tiene una gran cantidad de modulos desarrollados por la comunidad, aunque resolviste tu problema te recomiendo que veas el modulo views_slideshow, si aprendes a usar el modulo views de drupal no usaras nada mas, existen videos en internet q te pueden mostrar su funcionalidad. http://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow

Answer (score 1):

Por fin pude solucionar este problema. Al final decidí cambiar todo el código del carrusel por el mío y agregar unos estilos para corregir unos espacios en blanco, los cuales pude ocultar gracias a las sugerencias de mas usuarios en otro [tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39214/eliminar-espacio-en-blanco-bajo-el-slider-con-css-de-un-sitio-web/39421#39421) de esta web.

Comment: Es otra opción. Lo que yo te decía es buscar en los tipos de contenido que campos había y buscar uno con ese nombre, ejemplo: https://s23.postimg.org/ksk5saa1n/drupal.png